# Website To Upload Android App for Others to View

Tags: android

Is there a website to upload an Android app so that others may view?

This is for a class and the professor thought there may be some online emulators. The ones I found searching weren't really doing what I want to do.

I just want to upload the app so that the professor can use it to check it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can test the https://appetize.io/ for this, the purpose is to testing native apps.